# Logstash aggregate filter plugin on multiple logstash nodes

Tags: logstash

I'm interested in using the [logstash aggregate filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-howitworks) but I was wondering how this would work in my case where I have [multiple logstash nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/deploying-and-scaling.html#_scalability).

Also do i need to set - filter workers to 1 ( -w 1 flag) - if I don't mind the events are possessed out of sequence?

**Update**

My use case demands aggregating logs generated by multiple services by a unique trace-id. I have no [end event](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example3). Rather using a set window of say 3 seconds.

Comment: With what kind of shipper do you send the events to the logstash nodes? Filebeat?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill yes filebeat. I've added some more info on my use case in the question

Answer (score 0):

For the `aggregate` filter to work correctly you need to send the logs with the information you want to combine to the **same** logstash node.

If you are using a shipper, like Filebeat or any other, that sends events to multiple logstash nodes each node will aggregate only the events that it receives, you can't `aggregate` events from differents logstash nodes.

It is also recommended to set the workers to 1 because the main use for the `aggregate` filter is to get information from the events belonging to the same unique id (task id, job id, process id) and enrich a final event, if you use more than 1 worker, your `end` event could be processed before your `start` event, for example.

Comment: can Filebeat support stickiness and send events to a specific node based on some hash or id? it seems to me that it can't..

Comment: try adding `routing = %{id to aggregate on}`

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-routing

Comment: @binyamingreenberg no, you can't use any logic to send specific events to different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this can be tackled by a combination of design and config. Thought I'd drop in a few thoughts on the topic - for what it's worth.

1. Aggregation is limited to single worker - for obvious reasons. Which forces your design to restrict aggregation at a single point in your information flow. Sounds like a hub/ spoke-wheel pattern to me
2. If you have multiple logstashes - you will need to conditionally route events that DO need aggregation to this central logstash. I'd go with adding a "to-be-aggregated" tags (for example) which can be used for flow control
3. On the aggregator logstash itself - either implicitly aggregate everything that comes in - or use the above tag to decide which one to do or NOT. Obviously, this copy will need to run with pipeline.workers=1 AND pipeline.java_execution=false ([see here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/specifying-logstash-filter-workers/236089/2)).
4. That leaves the rest down to config? Which I think leads you back to the specific filter plugin [docs page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html)

This is what I am doing. Hope this helps..